# Regular expression for mm/yy in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am trying to execute a regular expression in SQL Server to match a `MM/YY` formatted `VARCHAR` string.

I have tried

```
WHERE ExpiryDate LIKE '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]'
```

which allows incorrect dates like `30/18`.

I also tried

```
WHERE ExpiryDate LIKE '0[1-9]|1[012]/[0-3][0-9]'
```

But SQL Server does not accept pipe separated as an OR operator.

I need the month to match 01 - 12

I can do

```
WHERE ExpiryDate LIKE '0[1-9]/[0-9][0-9]' 
   OR ExpiryDate LIKE '10/[0-9][0-9]'
   OR ExpiryDate LIKE '11/[0-9][0-9]'
   OR ExpiryDate LIKE '12/[0-9][0-9]'
```

but I would prefer it to be within the regular expression.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you could try to parse the string as date and then work with date functions

Comment: _"I would prefer it to be within the regular expression"_ Use the right tool.
Date function and cast can verify a date. I know it's cool to use a electric Hammer drill But when facing a nail use an regular Hammer.

Comment: You cannot convert 30/18 into a date, hence why I'm trying to filter down to valid MM/YY formats so I can convert them into dates and query against them.

Comment: Actually you are not using reg expr in MSSQL but pattern matching.  To validate dates you can use other solutions.

Comment: Take the 2 first char cast into int check if 0<X<13. Same for month part.

Comment: A nice question. It appeared as a result of common mixing LIKE wildcards with regexes.

Comment: @DragandDrop And the speed? Directly setting of allowed formats can be much faster.

Comment: You can extend your sql server with dotnet functions to provide a regex sql-function.

Comment: @Gangnus, If the string can be an invalid date, if a varchar is use to store a date. You know that this string can be anything. I just want his data to be in a proper type. Op wants to filter on data that you can't convert because it's not valid. IMO,  From that point speed do not matter anymore, the wall is in this way. And we are going  straight into it.

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+, you could use try_convert() to convert the expiration string into a date.  Try_Convert() will return a NULL value if the conversion fails.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int, ExpiryDate varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'09/17')
,(2,'30/17')


Select *
 From  @YourTable
 Where try_convert(date,replace(ExpiryDate,'/','/01/')) >= '2017-09-01'  
 -- Where try_convert(date,replace(ExpiryDate,'/','/01/')) is null
```

**Returns**

```
ID  ExpiryDate
1   09/17
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convalidate dates, you could try something like this:

```
 SET DATEFORMAT dmy
 ;WITH A AS (SELECT '18/12' AS EXPDATE UNION ALL SELECT '10/17' UNION ALL SELECT 'x2/16' )
 SELECT *, ISDATE('01/'+EXPDATE) AS CHK FROM A
```

Output:

```
EXPDATE CHK
18/12   0
10/17   1
x2/16   0
```

Comment: First time I made it for MM/DD.  Then I saw you asked MM/YY.  Answer changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
date LIKE '0[1-9]/[0-9][0-9]' OR
date LIKE '1[0-2]/[0-9][0-9]'
```

Is much shorter. But without | it is hard to make variants... Notice, that LIKE takes not regexes, but [wildcards](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Don't forget, that '[1-9]/[0-9][0-9]' can also happen. And other variants, with inner spaces and so on. If you are not absolutely sure in month format used, and don't depend on high speed, use @JohnCampeletti variant.